# Box API periodically returning 202 status codes

Tags: http, box-api

I have noticed that box has started to return 202 status codes on what appears to be a random basis on file upload API calls.  It appears that when this code is returned the file upload has not been completed successfully, so a retry of the attempted operation is necessary.  Here's an example response I am seeing:

```
["body"]=>
  bool(true)
["header"]=>
  string(211) "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2013 23:14:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store
Retry-After: 4
Content-Length: 0"
```

Given the ambiguous nature of a 202 response does anyone know what the technically appropriate response to this status code is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the full explanation in the [Download a File Section](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-download-a-file) (we didn't put it in the upload section but are now)

> If the file is not ready to be downloaded (i.e. in the case where the
>   file was uploaded immediately before the download request), a response
>   with an HTTP status of 202 Accepted will be returned with a
>   Retry-After header indicating the time in seconds after which the file
>   will be available for the client to download.

More or less this means that you'll have to wait 'Retry-After' seconds before you can actually download the file. Most apps won't need to immediately download the file, but in the event that one does, it needs to handle this response properly.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'll implement a back-off when these come back.  Could you explain what this means in the file upload context?  (i.e. if it means the file isn't ready to download, what does it mean for an upload?)

Comment: You shouldn't be seeing 202s on uploads anymore–are you seeing any?